# Entity Framework model navigation is broken

Tags: linq, entity-framework, code-first

I'm using EF, Repository pattern with services to access data and something strange has happened with my Data:

```
public interface IEntity {

    int ID { get; set; }
}
public partial class Page : IEntity {

    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    public UserProfile User { get; set; }

    int _id;
    [Key]
    public int ID {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; }
    }
}
public partial class Post : IEntity {     

    public Page Page { get; set; }

    int _id;
    [Key]
    public int ID {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; }
    }
}
```

So I have these code first models and this query used to work:

```
         var posts = (from p in postDb.GetAll()
                     where p.Page.User.ID == userId && p.Status == Status.Pending
                     select p);
```

I doesn't anymore because `p.Page = null`, even though data exists in the database. If I do something like: `select p.Page.Count()` -- I'll get the right count back, but if I do: `select p.Page`, nothing...

I don't get it how do I discover/fix whatever went wrong?

Comment: If you run the application in debug mode, do any exceptions occur?

Comment: no, no exceptions. Not even first chance exception in console.

Comment: any chance a virtual is missing on the Page property or the Fluent API no longer has the Foreign key declared?

Comment: Where is the `User` navigation property for the Page entity?  Seems like you are using DB-First then using DbContext generator to make it code first?

Comment: @Justin I've added User to the model, I have omitted a lot of unnecessary code.

Comment: @philsoady Why would I need a virtual modifier, it worked at one point without any being virtual. At the minute I can't get a .Include method to work successfully on my Repo for lazy loading either.

Comment: How are you returning the posts?  EG:  Are you trying to pass it to another method and it is wrapped inside of a `using` statement?  Perhaps you aren't materializing it before trying to use it else where.

Comment: have only seen/tried that working with virtual, nav properties. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx   no sure why it worked once for you.   Any chance the data was in the context at the time ?

Comment: How can you call `p.Page.Count()`? `p.Page` isn't a collection in your model, only a single reference.